# terra::distance only reports distance to NA raster cells

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I am attempting to use `terra::distance` as I would use `raster::distanceFromPoints`. However, `terra::distance` only reports the distance from the point(s) to NA cells. Is this the intended result? I include sample code with my workaround.

Raster plot with point for distance calculation

[image: plot or raster with diagonal NA cells and point at 50,50]

Plot of terra::distance for point

[image: terra::distance raster showing distance only calculated for NA cells]

Desired output

[image: workaround to get distance values using terra::distance]

```
r <- terra::rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
valR <- rep(1, length = 100)
valR[c(1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,100)] <- NA
terra::values(r) <- valR

xp <- c(50)
yp <- c(50)
xyp <- cbind(xp, yp)
vecP <- terra::vect(xyp)

terra::plot(r)
terra::plot(vecP, add=T)

rDist <- terra::distance(r, vecP)
terra::plot(rDist) #only NA cells have the distance value

# WORKAROUND
r1 = r*0
r1[is.na(r1)] <- 100
r1[r1<1] <- NA
r1Dist <- terra::distance(r1, vecP)
terra::plot(r1Dist)

####################
# using raster::distanceFromPoints
####################

rR <- raster::raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
raster::values(rR) <- valR
raster::plot(rR)

rRDist <- raster::distanceFromPoints(rR, xyp)
rRDist <- raster::mask(rRDist, rR)
raster::plot(rRDist)
```

Comment: From reading `?distance`, this looks more like a bug than intended behaviour to me (it seems to be using the method for when y is missing).   Hopefully, @RobertHijmans may see this and shed some light. I guess your workaround will keep you going until there's a better answer.

Comment: I do not see this problem with the development version. Can you try it? `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Comment: The development version works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this using distance to a SpatVector of lines rather than points. That seems to work as expected. I assume that maybe it has not been implemented for points yet.

So, another workaround you could use is to calculate distance to lines of zero length (which are basically equivalent to points):

```
x1 <- rbind(c(50,50), c(50,50))
colnames(x1) <- c('x', 'y')
lns <- vect(x1, "lines")

rDist <- distance(r, lns)
plot(rDist)
```

[image]